# When using "Try Ubuntu" from a removable flash drive, is it isolated from my main OS?

Tags: usb

I have a very expensive computer that I try my best to keep clean and virus free, but my little sister has managed to make the family computer unusable.  My parents are insisting that I "Share" with my poor little sister, and I'd like to avoid crippling my computer.

If I only allow her to use the "Try Ubuntu" feature on a flash drive with Ubuntu, could she manage to break things on the host machine?  Change files on the C: drive, install random malware to Windows, etc. etc.  I want her horrendous internet browsing habits to only impact the linux os and any files located on the flash drive, is this possible?

Comment: She could click the install option.

Comment: Running an operating system of a USB stick is becoming easier over time and what you may want to do for your sister is to create a persistent USB using Ubuntu or any other system she might be familiar with. The advantage of have a persistent USB would be that your sister will be able to save file that she might need on her USB and not on your computer. Here is a guide to creating persistent USBs. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: Another option is you can set her up a virtual machine on your computer, and you can always reset the virtual machine if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If she's running a LiveUSB of Ubuntu, and is only web browsing, it should be relatively safe.  It would be safer if you disconnected the hard drive in the machine when you aren't using it, as then it would be impossible (short of reconnecting it) to mount it and potentially trash things by fumbling about.

It all depends on how malicious she is, I suppose.

Comment: So to clarify a bit: without doing something like removing the hard drive, the answers to your questions above are: Yes, Yes, No, and Yes.